# How to send an array of values into database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

Ineed to send the array of html elements into different rows in database 
given below is the html code.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
<input type="text" name="user[]" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{ 
foreach($_POST['user'] as $key => $value)
{
echo $key." has the value = ". $value."<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove hash sign from action.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this....

```
<?php

$this->load->database();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{ 
    foreach($_POST['user'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $data = array('user'=>$value);
        $this->db->insert('table_name',$data); //Generated query >> INSERT INTO table_name(user) VALUES ('$value');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to send it to different rows of table

Comment: what is output of `print_r($_POST['user']);`.it will inserts in different rows.